# window authentication not working on IIS server

Tags: c#, window

I am using below code to get email address of user

```
  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
               string[] a = wi.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' }); // ' Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\')

               PrincipalContext dc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "logistics");
               UserPrincipal adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(dc, a[1]);
               UserEmailAddr = adUser.EmailAddress;
```

my web.config as

```
  <authentication mode="Windows">

  </authentication>
  <identity impersonate="false"/>
```

and in IIS server i only have window authentication enable all other option are disable.

Somehow its not working when deployed on the server.Any advice !!

Comment: Can you share your IIS authentication configuration as well? Because there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Serdar from where ? i dont have anything on web.confing . or are you looking particular in IIS server ?

Comment: Yes, because when you configure via web.config you may not put your config file into right folder. So need to check IIS server configuration which is something similar to this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/index/_static/image7.png

Comment: In IIS server Configuration , i have Windows Authentication "Enabled" and all other option are Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is the feature for windows authentication installed?

"The default installation of IIS 7 and later does not include the Windows authentication role service. To use Windows authentication on IIS, you must install the role service, disable Anonymous authentication for your Web site or application, and then enable Windows authentication for the site or application."
[Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)

Comment: @D Jordan Windows authentication is already installed. still not work.